# Editing ASPX page with Microsoft Word having XHTML code

Tags: asp.net, xslt

I have a xml file which has all the data from my Web based application. Now I am using XSLT 1.0 file to read the data from XML and my application then displays this in aspx page in my internet explorer.

I want to edit the content in Microsoft Word and then save it in word file (doc, docx). When I use File-->"Edit with Microsoft Word" option, I see blank MS Word and no data. I dont know what to do.

Please help and advise.

Answer (score 0):

Open it with notepad, then copy all the content, the paste it in a newly created word document.

That's how straightforward things tend to get with office...

Comment: Hi Serge, Thanks for reply. My application actually generates the output to IE (aspx). If I use Edit-->Notepad, it opens in notepad with the all the codes and not the tables and data. I am sorry if my answer makes no sense. Please advise